# Include php file in function + pass the variable to the included file

Tags: php, include

I need to include .php file in function. It's working fine, but I need to pass some variable(s) to the included file

functions.php

```
$variable_i_need_to_pass = 123;
function IncludeFile($file_to_include) //just an example, my include function have some checkings (is file, setting global incl folder, etc..)
{
    require_once $file_to_include;
}
```

menu.php

```
echo $variable_i_need_to_pass; //undefined / NULL
```

index.php

```
require_once('functions.php');
IncludeFile('menu.php');
```

Comment: Slightly odd mechanism, but you could pass it as a param like `function IncludeFile($file_to_include, $someValue)`

Comment: **You really are making life difficult!** Why do you need a function to call an require_once. **You are not adding anything but complexity.** Remember variable scope!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know, but i'd need to pass the variables every time i make one.

Comment: `function IncludeFile($file_to_include, $someValue=NULL) { If ($someValue !== NULL) { ....}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to change the path of the file including... So when I make a folder I don't need to worry about finding the right path

Comment: See `__DIR__` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: @RiggsFolly $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] isn't enough because my hosting have more folders. So I'd still need to make some path changing

Comment: @RiggsFolly same story with __DIR__

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, I've solved it. With $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + directories set as variable. Then passing the variable to include-require adding also the file i want to include. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So I made a variable and then passing it to all my include/require functions.

```
$global_path = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/domains/example.domain/my_project_folder";

require_once "{$global_path}/incl/footer.php";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).